# How to rewrite .php to .html with mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Prolly an easy one.. I am trying to study up on mod_rewrite and ran into an issue

Here is my url

```
example.com/index.php?id=1&title=some_title
```

I want the page to be able to take

```
example.com/1/some_title.html
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\w+).html$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2
```