# How do rewrite urls to querystring and ilas name with html extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How i do rewrite urls the following by .htacess:

"http://www.domain.com/blog/"   To "http://www.domain.com/blog.html"

and

"http://www.domain.com/general.php?code2" To "http://www.domain.com/this-is-ilas.html"

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display SEO friendly URLs using mod\_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513311/how-can-i-display-seo-friendly-urls-using-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple rule with `mod_rewrite`:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog\.html$ /blog/ [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^this-is-ilas\.html$ /general.php?code2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It will allow you to change how your URLs appear to the user, while still calling the correct script on the backend. This includes masking any PHP urls to display as `.html`. A possible solution (though it may need some work; place it in your `.htaccess` file):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ilas\.html$ general.php?=2
```

See also: [How to rewrite .php to .html with mod_rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162447/how-to-rewrite-php-to-html-with-mod-rewrite-rules)

Comment: It's a comment not an answer!

Comment: The question was "how do you rewrite urls". "Use mod_rewrite" seems to be an appropriate answer to said question.

Comment: i want general.php?=2 to ilas.html